# Controller "Controller name" couldn't be instantiated SAPUI

Tags: sapui5

I'm getting an error while I'm trying to navigate to another page in the sapui5 application. I'm trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. The directory Structure of my application is as below:
[image: Project Folder]

In manifest file

```
"routes": [{
        "pattern": "",
        "name": "appHome",
        "target": "home"
     }
        , {
            "pattern": "Course/{courseId}",
            "name": "course",
            "target": "course"
        }],
     "targets": {
        "home": {
           "viewName": "Home",
           "viewLevel" : 1
        },
        "notFound": {
           "viewName": "NotFound",
           "transition": "show"
        } ,
        "course": {
            "viewPath": "dlesDLESdashboard.view.Course",
            "viewName": "CourseDetail",
            "viewLevel" : 2
        }
     }
  },
```

When I click on my navigate button I am triggering this event by default I'm giving static ID later I'll change.

```
   handleCourseClick : function(oEvent){
       this.getRouter().navTo("course",{courseId :"222222"});},
```

I'm not sure this information is good enough to find out my error or not. 
The Error is that when I click on the tile I'm getting this error instead of navigating to my course detail page. 
[image: Error when clicking on tile]

Comment: In your View and the controller check if you have correctly defined the controller. Also check for syntax errors in your controller.

Comment: What's the exact namespace of controller? What does your view say in controllerName attribute? Are your resource roots registered correctly? Could be a ParseError either (just post your entire controller on the console to test).

Comment: without attribute, it works fine. but I've changed the setting and pass attribute on click event after that i got error. I've also one more navigation which is without attribute and that works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your controller, there might be something wrong with your view and controller connection. check namespace, name of controller etc and verify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sap.ui.define([   
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "locations/util/Utils",
    "locations/controller/BaseController"
], function(BaseController, JSONModel, Utils) {
```

I declared these in the wrong order, and caused the same problem.